# How to GROUP BY multiple columns with multiple HAVING values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, having

I am trying to create a mysql query that looks at a table that stores search queries. The query is trying to get all rows that:

- `>=` to a date
- Only returning rows where the search query has 3 or more occurrences
- Also only returning rows where 2 or more users have used a search query

This query does not work, but should outline what Im trying to do:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  `analytics` 
WHERE 
  `date` >= '2021-01-01' 
GROUP BY 
  `query` 
HAVING 
  COUNT(*) >= 3 
  AND 
GROUP BY 
  `user` 
HAVING 
  COUNT(*) >= 2 
ORDER BY 
  id DESC;
```

**Example Data**

| id | user | query | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | What is a dog | 2021-01-01 |
| 2 | 5 | What is a dog | 2021-01-01 |
| 3 | 6 | What is a dog | 2021-01-01 |
| 4 | 7 | What is a dog | 2021-01-01 |
| 5 | 7 | What is a brog | 2021-01-01 |

**Example SQL**

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  analytics 
WHERE 
  date >= '2021-01-01' 
GROUP BY 
  query 
HAVING 
  COUNT(*) >= 3 
  AND 
GROUP BY 
  user 
HAVING 
  COUNT(*) >= 2 
ORDER BY 
  id DESC;
```

With the values set in the query above, a single row should return with the query "What is a dog", all other columns don't really matter.

I know you can comma separate columns to GROUP BY but I can't seem to figure out how to have different values for each column.

Comment: Please post table description, sample data and expected result in text format

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results as per [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @ErgestBasha Updated with examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set both conditions in the same `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT `query` 
FROM `analytics` 
WHERE `date` >= '2021-01-01' 
GROUP BY `query`
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3 AND COUNT(DISTINCT `user`) >= 2;
```

Comment: @ErgestBasha why not?

Comment: @ErgestBasha this is exactly why "What is a brog" should be returned: it occurs at least 3 times and for more than 2 users. I don't understand what you don't understand.

Comment: make it group by user and COUNT(Distinct 'query') >= 2 maybe?' Depends exactly what you want.

Comment: This works exactly as needed. @forpas is correct, in your example "What is a brog" should also come up because it has been searched 3 or more times and by 2 or more different users. Thanks!